# How do I get code analysis to ignore line breaks in my resource files?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, resource-files

Is there a way to get code analysis to ignore line breaks `<br>` when giving me spelling warnings about text in my resource files? I know I can add them to my code analysis dictionary but I'm pretty sure there is a way to get them ignored without that.

The warning is the standard CA1703 warning which for `br` tags gives me something like:

> correct the spelling of 'br' in string value 'blah blah `<br>` blah'

This is a normal winform project using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a file called CustomDictionary.xml to your project

That looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>br</Word>
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

or may be <br>, may be, never used it on tags.

More info on it here [VS Code Analysis and dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx)

Comment: yeah, I know I can add them to the dictionary but isnt there a way to get them ignored without that? I feel like I'm missing something simple. Thx -CM

Comment: You could supress it into the global supression file and then edit that, so it would accept more targets. That turns out to be less simple that CustomDictionary though, and a bit of a non-standard approach.

Comment: After some more research I am convinced there really isnt another way to do it so I'm marking this answer as correct. Thx